# Android studio not recognizing Latest version code or new window type for Oreo

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I have an ionic project that I've been able to build for some time.  Somehow the build configuration got screwed up and now I am left in this state.  The IDE (and the build process) don't recognize the lastest version code `Build.VERSION_CODES.O` or a window type that was added in Oreo `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY`.
[image]

in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file I have: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />`

I also have all of the latest SDK versions installed in android studio:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the [latest version of cordova only supports android api version 25](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/).  Somehow in working in the android files within android studio I had modified it and it was working targetting api version 26, but after rebuilding from source that is no longer. `Build.VERSION_CODES.O` or a window type that was added in Oreo `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` are only recognized in api version 26 & up.